# JSON Parsing Error?

Tags: iphone

I am using JSON (SBJson) but it's giving  the error :

```
JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x5f2f7f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}.
```

am using this web service : "http://xoap.weather.com/search/search?where=India"
please give me the solutions why does error come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That response is XML (`application/xml`), not JSON (`application/json`).

Answer (score 5):

That URL returns XML, not JSON. The "illegal character" is the first bracket in the XML, which isn't a valid character in JSON.