# Urls Which return JSON object?

Tags: iphone

can anybody give me the urls which return the JSON objects or we can say application/json to end user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590798/json-parsing-error), it seems that Weather.com does not support JSON (from my Googling).

You may need to use a different service, or convert the XML to JSON, or just read the XML.

The mime type `application/json` is returned, not sent as part of the request.

Answer (score 2):

http://codeasp.net/articles/asp-net/222/how-to-shorten-url-with-jquery

http://codeasp.net/articles/asp-net/217/calling-web-service-using-jquery-in-asp-net

http://codeasp.net/articles/asp-net/214/cascading-dropdownlist-using-jquery-and-asp-net

http://codeasp.net/articles/asp-net/212/using-jquery-autocomplete-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

@Raman Rana try this

http://www.unpossible.com/misc/lucky_numbers.json

This will return some numbers and for more information follow the tutorial....

> http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/

Hope this may help u!